# How to remove port from the url http://<ip>:8080

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, reverse-proxy

My spring boot web application is deployed in GCP  and accessible in the url http://sampleip:8080/.I want to remove the port from url so that the application is accessible via url http://sampleip/.
Tried with zulu with below config , but didnt work.What am i missing
Please advise on how this can be achieved ?

below is my pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.7</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.verofax</groupId>
    <artifactId>ABIMVP</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>ABIMVP</name>
    <description>ABI POC</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud.tools/appengine-maven-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.8</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-openfeign -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.4</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.16</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Added Zulu annotaion in mail class
@EnableFeignClients
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
public class AbimvpApplication {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AbimvpApplication.class, args);
    }
```

Below is my property file

```
ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
zuul.routes.userservice.path=/**
zuul.routes.userservice.url=http://localhost:8080/
```

Comment: I don't have many details, but after looking on Yahoo & Google Search... I found many websites (and even topics here on Stackoverflow) that address exactly that. I'd recommend to use the Search.

Comment: Change the port number from 8080 to 80. However, running a program that opens port 80 requires privilege. That is not recommended. Instead, use a proxy such as Nginx or Apache to proxy port 80 to 8080. Also, consider using TLS (port 443).

Comment: Did you try to add `server.port=80` in your property file?

Comment: changing the port to 80 worked for me. Thanks all for your help

Answer (score 0):

after reading all the comments, and your question, well, the main solution would be to change your port to 80... But if you have more than one service running this will be a pain...

So I recommend you to use SpringCloud Gateway, It's pretty simple to use and you can map everything inside it to hide ports... just do something like this in the configuration class(You can also do similar in properties yml)

```
package com.verofax.gateway.config;

import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteLocator;
import org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.builder.RouteLocatorBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SpringCloudConfig {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator gatewayRoutes(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r.path("/SomeFolder/**")
                        .uri("http://YourIp:8080/"))

                .route(r -> r.path("/SomeFolder/OtherFolder/**")
                        .uri("http://YourURL:8085/"))

                .route(r -> r.path("/**")
                        .uri("http://IP_ADDRESS:8087/"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

So, First route will redirect traffic from 8080 to SomeFolder. Last route will redirect traffic from 8087(it can be any port, even 8080) to your main website, so anyone clicking on http://sampleip:8080/ with last route will be able to reach http://sampleip/ without any effort.

If you have more than one service running(different ports with websites) I recommend to you to put all images and CSS files in the project you will leave as path /** (without folder name) to avoid creating any static folder or static projects... Otherwise your websites will have broken css/images.

Hope this suits for you :)